# Accessing file/image in cloud bucket in secure & efficient way

Tags: php, cloud, cloud-storage

Images of a project I'm working on have been stored in Cloud Bucket. I have to provide images for APP development via API but I don't want to send the actual link.

One solution I found was sending encoded(base 64) images, but it is not an efficient way. And also I don't want to keep Cloud Storage Details in App side.

Looking for a best solution in terms of security and efficient for this problem.

Comment: which cloud storage service you are using?

Comment: I'm using Google Storage, but here my question is whatever the Storage.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the signed URL would be the best approach. 
Set read-only permission and expiry date as per your need.

For google cloud storage: Refer to this [Access control google cloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)